# Prevent image resizing in bootstrap Card

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want a Card that has a non-resized image with a grey background. The Card is bigger than the size of the image.
I got the background and my image, but I don't manage to prevent the image from resizing.

```
<div className ="container" id="mainContainer">
  <div className ="row mt-4">
    <div className="col-md-4">
      <div className="card" >
        <img  className="card-img-top bg-light mb-3" alt="" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png">
         </img>
         <div className="card-img-overlay">
           <span className="badge badge-dark"> 1 </span>
         </div>
         <div className="card-body">
           <h5 className="card-title"> Bulbasur  </h5>
           <span className="badge badge-light"> poison </span>
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like this
[image: what I want]

but I got this[image: what I have]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the image in its own container DIV, and use `w-auto` to override the width:100% behavior of `card-img-top`

```
         <div class="card">
            <div class="text-center bg-light">
                <img class="card-img-top mb-3 w-auto" alt="" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png">
            </div>
            <div class="card-img-overlay">
                <span class="badge badge-dark"> 1 </span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"> Bulbasur  </h5>
                <span class="badge badge-light"> poison </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

https://codeply.com/go/ACgUKJQMea

Comment: That does not result in the picture I wanted. The grey background is not covering all the image space

Comment: Then move `bg-light` to the containing div

Answer (score 0):

in your own CSS file, add an additional definition for .img-responsive

```
.img-responsive 
{ 
    width:100%;
}
```

replace code to

```
<img  className="card-img-top bg-light mb-3 img-responsive " alt="" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1.png">
</img>
```